# How to use Control->Invoke()?

Tags: .net, winforms, delegates, c++-cli

I'm not sure about the correct usage of Control->Invoke() with .NET, C++ and Windows Forms.

For example with such a method:

```
System::Void UI::setStatusText(System::String^ text) {
    if (this->InvokeRequired) {
        SetTextDelegate^ d = gcnew SetTextDelegate(this, &UI::setStatusText);
        statusLabel->Invoke(d, gcnew array<Object^> { text }); // <-- System.ExecutionEngineException
    } else
        statusLabel->Text = text;
}
```

Is it correct?? This method is executed by an arbitrary thread and should change the text of the statusLabel.

The delegate is declared as:

```
delegate void SetTextDelegate(System::String^ text);
```

But quite often I get a System.ExecutionEngineException in the marked line.

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks,
Martin

edit: visual studio says there is an unmanaged exception of the type System.ExecutionEngineException in mscorlib.dll and the green debug arrow points to the marked line. This is the stack trace: http://sharetext.org/B8RR . But how can I get the inner exception? Or if this is not caused by these code lines, what else can I do to figure out the error?

Comment: What's the message of the exception? Does it have inner exception? If yes, what is it?

Comment: It is *very* unlikely that it has anything to do with this code.  FEEE is typically generated when the managed heap is corrupted.  That's done by code that ran earlier, typically native code.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate code seems to be correct. But I don't understand what are you doing. You are creating a delegate that creates the same function setStatusText!! I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
delegate void SetTextDelegate();

System::Void UI::setStatusText(System::String^ text)
{
  statusLabel->Text = text
}

System::Void UI::ANOTHER_FUNCTION(System::String^ text)
{   
   SetTextDelegate^ d = gcnew SetTextDelegate(this, &UI::setStatusText);
   statusLabel->Invoke(d, gcnew array<Object^> { text });
}
```